# Расположение шрифта в placeholder по вертикали

Tags: html, css

В общем, проблема такая: шрифт `placeholder` должен быть маленьким, а вводимое, большим.

Пытался через `::placeholder` изменить `font`, но тогда идет выравнивание по нижней части, как показано на скрине.

[image: Скрин следствия]

```
body{
font-size:15px;
}
.send_input{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 620px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;


    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}

::placeholder{
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```

`Margin` не работают с плэйсхолдером.

Comment: Геморройно это. Лично я видел лишь input c padding:0 внутри div-а, сделанного под input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте: `transform:translateY(-XX);`

```css
body {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.send_input {
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 620px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: calc(2rem + 2.875rem);
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2.875rem;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: .8rem;
  transform: translateY(-.25rem);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: .8rem;
  transform: translateY(-.25rem);
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: .8rem;
  transform: translateY(-.25rem);
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-size: .8rem;
  transform: translateY(-.25rem);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="send_input" placeholder="Some placeholder text">
</form>
```